# maven dependency scope for mojo exec:java

Tags: maven

I want to run a local activemq broker for jmeter tests with:

```
mvn exec:java -PJMeterProfile
```

I have some deps in provided scope, causing java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError, like

```
            <dependency>
                    <groupId>org.slf4j</groupId>
                    <artifactId>slf4j-api</artifactId>
                    <version>1.6.4</version>
                    <scope>provided</scope>
            </dependency>
            <dependency>
                    <groupId>org.slf4j</groupId>
                    <artifactId>slf4j-log4j12</artifactId>
                    <version>1.6.4</version>
                    <scope>provided</scope>
            </dependency>
            <dependency>
                    <groupId>log4j</groupId>
                    <artifactId>log4j</artifactId>
                    <version>1.2.17</version>
                    <scope>provided</scope>
            </dependency>
```

Is there some scope apropriated to maven provide this classes only for exec:java?
Or how other way to provide this dependency only in exec:java?

Resolved adding dependency to mojo plugin like sugested by tom ( and adding includePluginDependencies true ):

```
                    <plugin>
                            <groupId>org.codehaus.mojo</groupId>
                            <artifactId>exec-maven-plugin</artifactId>
                            <configuration>
                                    <mainClass>${target.main.class}</mainClass>
                                    <commandlineArgs>${target.cmd.args}</commandlineArgs>
                                    <includePluginDependencies>true</includePluginDependencies>
                            </configuration>
                            <dependencies>
                                    <dependency>
                                            <groupId>org.slf4j</groupId>
                                            <artifactId>slf4j-api</artifactId>
                                            <version>1.6.4</version>
                                            <scope>compile</scope>
                                    </dependency>
                                    <dependency>
                                            <groupId>org.slf4j</groupId>
                                            <artifactId>slf4j-log4j12</artifactId>
                                            <version>1.6.4</version>
                                            <scope>compile</scope>
                                    </dependency>
                                    <dependency>
                                            <groupId>log4j</groupId>
                                            <artifactId>log4j</artifactId>
                                            <version>1.2.17</version>
                                            <scope>compile</scope>
                                    </dependency>
                            </dependencies>
                    </plugin>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I believe you can add the dependencies to the plugin itself.  That way they are added when the plugin is executed.

Check out [this](http://mojo.codehaus.org/exec-maven-plugin/examples/example-exec-using-plugin-dependencies.html) url.